# Count File Status Time in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

Suppose I have table **FileLog** with data look like this.

`+-----+------+---------------------+-----------+
|logId|fileId|timestamp            |status     |
+-----+------+---------------------+-----------+
|1    |1     |"2014-03-04 01:00:00"|inProgress |
+-----+------+---------------------+-----------+
|2    |1     |"2014-03-04 01:30:00"|onHold     |
+-----+------+---------------------+-----------+
|3    |1     |"2014-03-05 01:00:00"|inProgress |
+-----+------+---------------------+-----------+
|4    |1     |"2014-03-05 02:00:00"|onHold     |
+-----+------+---------------------+-----------+
|5    |1     |"2014-03-06 01:00:00"|inProgress |
+-----+------+---------------------+-----------+
|6    |1     |"2014-03-06 01:30:00"|complete   |
+-----+------+---------------------+-----------+
|7    |2     |"2014-03-05 01:00:00"|inProgress |
+-----+------+---------------------+-----------+
|8    |2     |"2014-03-05 02:00:00"|complete   |
+-----+------+---------------------+-----------+`

In this table I am maintaining file status (**In Progress** or **On Hold** or **Complete**) with timestamp. Now I want file wise total time in which file was in status **inProgress.**

   So expected output should be something like this for given data.

`+------+----------+
|fileId| time(min)|
+------+----------+
|1     |120       |
+------+----------+
|2     |60        |
+------+----------+`

If possible, I want the result without sub-query because of performance issues.

Comment: It looks, from your question, like you hope to retrieve the total time for which each distinct fileId item was in progress, but not on hold and not complete. Is that correct? In other words, your FileLog rows represent status changes, and you want time-in-status. Right?

Comment: yes Ollie.. you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got my answer without sub query. Its very fast solution. 
SQL Fiddle : [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a766b2/12)

```
SELECT a.fileId, 
SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(COALESCE(b.t,UTC_TIMESTAMP),a.t))/60) as fileTimeInMin
    FROM FileLog a
    LEFT JOIN FileLog b
    ON a.fileId = b.fileid
    AND b.status IN ('onHold', 'complete')
    AND b.t > a.t
    LEFT JOIN FileLog c ON a.fileId = c.fileId
     AND c.t > a.t AND c.t < b.t
WHERE a.status = 'inProgress'
AND c.t is null
    GROUP BY a.fileId;
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, you want the total time a fileid is in progress (ie, time between an inProgress record and either an onHold or complete record).

If so this should do it:-

```
SELECT fileId, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, time_inProgress, time_onHold)) AS TotalTime
FROM
(
    SELECT a.fileId, a.t AS time_inProgress, MIN(b.t) AS time_onHold
    FROM FileLog a
    INNER JOIN FileLog b
    ON a.fileId = b.fileid
    AND a.status = 'inProgress'
    AND b.status IN ('onHold', 'complete')
    AND b.t > a.t
    GROUP BY a.fileId, a.t
) Sub1
GROUP BY fileId;
```

SQL fiddle for it here:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a766b2/1

Also, not sure what you want to do with items that are in progress but have no onHold or complete date yet. Assuming in this case you want to count the time between inProgress and the current date / time:-

```
SELECT fileId, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, time_inProgress, time_onHold)) AS TotalTime
FROM
(
    SELECT a.fileId, a.t AS time_inProgress, MIN(IFNULL(b.t, NOW())) AS time_onHold
    FROM FileLog a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN FileLog b
    ON a.fileId = b.fileid
    AND b.status IN ('onHold', 'complete')
    AND b.t > a.t
    WHERE a.status = 'inProgress'
    GROUP BY a.fileId, a.t
) Sub1
GROUP BY fileId;
```

Comment: Hi @Kickstart you understood question perfect. but is it possible to get this result without sub-query? because I have data in millions row..so it's performance issue.

Comment: Afraid I can't think of a way of doing it without a sub query.

Comment: Hi..@Kickstart.. I have one question here that if I use different timezones on my database server and application server, then is it safe to use date function like NOW in query?

Comment: Depends how critical the time difference is. NOW() is only used for finding the time of a status that is still 'inProgress', and it will depend on whether the time stamp on the database was populated by the database when the record was inserted or from your application.

Answer (score 1):

This is a time series problem. Each row represents a state transition, and you are looking for time-in-state, not overall elapsed time between start and finish for each item.

So, we need to start with a query that will present a row for each time interval in your table.  This query will do that.  It's nasty for the first and last time interval for each item (each `fileId`) but that doesn't matter.  I have changed the name of your `timestamp` column to `stamp` because I don't like using reserved words for column names.

Here is the query (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53fe8/3/0). Each row represents an interval of time:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, @prevStamp, stamp) AS timediff,
       @prevStamp AS stamp,
       @prevStatus AS status,
       @prevFileId AS fileId,
       @prevStamp := stamp AS newstamp,
       @prevStatus := status AS newstatus,
       @prevFileId := fileId AS newfileid
  FROM FileLog,
       (SELECT @prevStamp := NULL,
               @prevStatus := NULL,
               @prevFileId := NULL) AS r
 ORDER BY fileId, stamp
```

I put in some columns we won't need in the final result just to convince myself it is correct.

Now, we need to aggregate this query to get total "inProgress" times.  That's pretty easy once we have the subquery that represents processing intervals rather than state change events (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53fe8/6/0).

```
SELECT SUM(timediff) in_progress_time, 
       MAX(newstamp) latest_time, 
       fileid
  FROM (
          /* time interval subquery */
          SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, @prevStamp, stamp) AS timediff,
                 @prevStamp AS stamp,
                 @prevStatus AS status,
                 @prevFileId AS fileId,
                 @prevStamp := stamp AS newstamp,
                 @prevStatus := status AS newstatus,
                 @prevFileId := fileId AS newfileid
            FROM FileLog,
                 (SELECT @prevStamp := NULL,
                         @prevStatus := NULL,
                         @prevFileId := NULL) AS r
           ORDER BY fileId, stamp
       ) AS tis
 WHERE status = 'inProgress'
 GROUP BY status, fileId 
 ORDER BY fileId
```

Lo and behold, the result set you need.

@Kickstart discovered a defect in my query. What happens when a particular fileId is still inProgress when the query is run? The query returns a rubbish in_progress_time.  Good catch!

Here's a fix to that, which uses the current time. I added a test case for it to the sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef1e8/23/0

```
SELECT SUM(timediff) in_progress_time, 
       MAX(newstamp) latest_time, 
       fileid
  FROM (
          /* time interval subquery */
          SELECT IF(fileId = @prevFileId, 
                    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, @prevStamp, stamp),
                    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, @prevStamp, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
                             AS timediff,
                 @prevStamp AS stamp,
                 @prevStatus AS status,
                 @prevFileId AS fileId,
                 @prevStamp := stamp AS newstamp,
                 @prevStatus := status AS newstatus,
                 @prevFileId := fileId AS newfileid
            FROM FileLog,
                 (SELECT @prevStamp := NULL,
                         @prevStatus := NULL,
                         @prevFileId := NULL) AS r
           ORDER BY fileId, stamp
       ) AS tis
 WHERE status = 'inProgress'
 GROUP BY status, fileId 
 ORDER BY fileId
```

You can substitute 0 for CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, and then any items that are still in progress won't be have that current progress counted at all.

Here's the thing about this query. Even though it looks complex, it makes a single pass over the data. Other approaches to this kind of report might do a self-join, which drives up the work the MySQL server has to do to satisfy the query.

*Performance tip*

It may, or may not, help performance of this query to create a covering index on `(fileId, stamp, status)`.  This may allow the subquery doing `ORDER BY fileId, stamp` to run in natural order rather than requiring a so-called filesort.

Comment: Hi..Ollie thanks for your quick response..I am getting perfect results from your query but is it possible to get results without sub-query? because it's performance issue.

Comment: It is not possible to avoid the subquery, as far as I know.  This subquery, however, is not a self join.  But, you should keep in mind that there's nothing magical about subqueries that causes them to be slow.  If you have years of data you may wish to restrict your query by date.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using this kind of query while generating reports for all data..so can't use date range :(

Comment: Isn't this SQL going to give incorrect results if (say) the latest status for fileid 1 is 'inProgress'? In such a case the timediff would be between the timestamp of the last  status for fileid 1 and the first timestamp (whatever the status) for fileid 2.

Comment: Hi..@Ollie.. if I use different timezones on my database server and application server, then is it safe to use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in query?

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia You can use zero instead of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to avoid counting in-progress items. Your question about time zones should be a new question, rather than a comment string.